# Formulating a logical constraints - integer linear programming

Tags: logic, integer-programming

If I have two binary(0-1) decision variables: $P_1$ and $P_2$, and my constraint is that:

$P_2$ may be chosen if and only if $P_1$ is **not** chosen, is this equivalent to the formulation that:
$$P_1 + P_2=1$$

Comment: "May be" sounds optional. Does the condition allow that neither variable is chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive linear constraints via conjunctive normal form as follows.
$$
P_2 \iff \lnot P_1 \\
(P_2 \implies \lnot P_1) \land (\lnot P_1 \implies P_2) \\
(\lnot P_2 \lor \lnot P_1) \land (P_1 \lor P_2) \\
(1 - P_2) + (1 - P_1) \ge 1 \land P_1 + P_2 \ge 1 \\
1 \ge P_2 + P_1 \land P_1 + P_2 \ge 1 \\
P_1 + P_2 = 1
$$